# How to replay video with swift

Tags: swift, xcode, video

How to replay video automatic. for example when the video done I want the video play again automatic.

this is my code:

```
videoURL = URL(string: video.url!)!
self.player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
let videoLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
videoLayer.frame = view.bounds
videoLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
self.videoSnap.layer.addSublayer(videoLayer)

let asset = AVURLAsset.init(url: videoURL!)
let duration = asset.duration.seconds
print(duration)
self.player.play()
```

Answer (score 0):

You've just to add an observer. Thanks to it, when the video is going to finish, it will allow you to replay the video again and again.

To do that, I recommend you this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42943416/6155942).